# Почему запрос заносит данные в предпоследнюю запись, когда нужно в последнюю?

Tags: php, mysql

```
require_once 'connect.php';
global $connect;  
$query13 = "UPDATE `result` SET `ocenka` = '$osenka' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1";
$result1 = mysqli_query($connect,$query13);
```

Comment: Я только начинаю свой путь в этой сфере, что нужно исправить?

Comment: надо изучить информацию по базовому синтаксису SQL запросов

Comment: Это к сожалению не ответ на мой вопрос, очень нужна помощь, кто понимает, подскажите что не так, нужно что бы данные заносили в последнюю запись в БД, а он не заносит, и изменяет предпоследнюю.

Comment: я же сказал, синтаксис UPDATE изучи http://2sql.ru/novosti/sql-update/

Comment: @Jean-Claude Вы не правы. Обновлять ВСЕ строки не будет. тут есть сортировка и LIMIT 1.

Comment: @CoderYooda но обновлять именно так – это бред))

Answer (score 0):

У вас правильный запрос и он установит значение `ocenka` в таблице `result` у последней записи в таблице сортированной по `id`.
Возможные проблемы:

- Где то позже создаётся еще одна запись
- При проверке в менеджере SQL убедитесь что таблица отсортирована по
  `id`

Comment: Так в том то и дело, я делаю программу тестирования, и почему то обновляется только предпоследняя запись. То есть, я допустим прохожу тест, таблица result обновляется, и поле osenka пустое, еще раз пройду, создаться новая строка, с тем же пустым полем, но предыдущая обновиться... Что с этим делать не понимаю

Comment: Ну php это синхронный (в большинстве случаев) язык. Я со 100% вероятностью могу сказать, что в момент выполнения вашего кода, обновляется именно последняя запись. То есть Ваша проблема не в этом месте.

Comment: Ладно спасибо за помощь! На диплом иду, и раньше запрос работал, все корректно, решил все перепроверить и столкнулся с этой проблемой, и как ее решить беспонятия.